# Change encoding of publish script for Visual Studio database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, publish, advanced-installer

We have a database project in Visual Studio that we use to create the deployment scripts for our database. This project is published using visual studio as well as MSBuild for our automated build. The publish script contains non-latin characters, i.e. Cyrillic/Mandarin.

The generated publish script are created with UTF-8 BOM, which conflicts with our installer application making the installed script insert gibberish in the database tables upon deployment. We need to change the publish script's encoding to just UTF-8 so that our installer can consume the script properly.

Things we tried are:

1. Add `.editorconfig` to the database project
2. Change all input `.sql` files to UTF-8
3. Try to add an after-publish task

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you